# How to calculate mean (Expected Value) of a custom continuous distribution from the probability density in R

Tags: r, mean, distribution, integral, continuous

The probability density and the calculation for the mean "by hand" are given below: [image]

I have coded the probability density function as:

```
myfunc <- function(x){
  ifelse(x >= 0 & x < 0.5, 1,
         ifelse (x >= 0.5 & x < 1, 0.2,
                 ifelse(x >= 1 & x < 2, 0.8*(x-1), 0)))
}
```

I understand that the EV is the weighted integral but I am struggling to code the calculation.

Also, additionally: how could I simulate this (0.867) result over the long run?

Could someone help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution with `integrate`:

```
integrate(function(x) x*myfunc(x),lower=0,upper=2)

0.866666666666667 with absolute error < 9.6e-15
```

Comment: Thanks, @one, looks like a great (& clean) solution. I'll have to get my head round how it actually works, but I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: ```integrate``` is a base R function that performs integral. The first argument is the function, which would be x f(x). The lower and upper are the range of the integral.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation, @one, I appreciate it.  It felt like integrate had too many arguments (`function(x) x*myfunc(x)`) somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`integrate` approach by one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77202361/12158757) is definitely the best to give you the analytical result.

If you are interested in a Monte Carlo simulation approach (you used the word ***"simulate"*** in your question), you can try something like below

```
> n <- 1e7

> x <- runif(n, 0, 2)

> y <- runif(n, 0, 2)

> 4 * mean(y <= x * myfunc(x))
[1] 0.8666928
```

The point is that you need have sufficiently large number `n` to approach the analytical mean value.

---

The idea of simulation is calculating the area portion under the curve `x*myfunc(x)`

```
ff <- \(v) v * myfunc(v)
curve(ff, 0, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice shade, which parameter did you use? 

Comment: @jay.sf haha, nothing fancy but just handmade sketch:p

Comment: Thank you very much, @ThomasIsCoding, I wish I could accept 2 answers, you addressed the simulation part, which was also very important for me. I appreciate the time & effort you took to answer me.